# ASP.NET Core service in zombie state if a thread fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I have a non-typical ASP.NET Core web service. It has a feature component, `BigF`, which starts a separate thread. I know it is a bad idea to start a worker service in the `aspnet` process, but I cannot stop this. It is a company thing.

When this thread from `BigF` fails, the web service also seems affected and returns 502 for all requests.

My expectations are:

- a worker thread in the `aspnet` process crashes, the whole application should crash.
- the crashed worker thread won't affect the `aspnet` thread, and the parts of the ASP.NET Core application should still work

However, it seems the ASP.NET Core application stays in a zombie state. It cannot handle any request, but the application won't exit.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Separate thread you mean ``Thread.Start`` or ``Task.Run`` ?

Comment: They used an `IHostedService`, and in the implementation, they used `Thread.Start`.

Comment: [mre] pls? We can't guess your code. Q doesn't even include how "BigF" interacts with the rest nor what it even does in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core you can configure `HostOptions` and set if there is an exception on `HostedService` still continue work, so if you're using `HostedService` to run a worker I think this would help:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<HostOptions>(options =>
{
    // default value is BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.StopHost
    options.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior = BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: I think this is the right direction. Thanks a lot.